# How can I hide a row, dependant on a varying values in a column

Tags: excel, vba

within Excel, I need a macro that would hide some rows when a few particular values appear in one column.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to hide the columns when you edit the values. You can bind the event to a button and do like this

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  Columns("BG").Hidden = True
  Columns("AK:EG").Hidden = False
End Sub
```